# JQuery chained filter dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement chained filter dropdown using just javascript - jquery.

The solution I need is http://www.codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery.

However I can't use this solution as it depends on a PHP file. Are there ways to implement this solely using javascript (client and/or serverside)?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple jQuery plugin that doesn't need any other datasource or data file.  You can use:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/

All the options get defined in the JS code, hopefully you wont have a large dataset.

```
<input type="text" name="demo1" />

    var option_tree = {
       "Option 1": {"Suboption":200},
       "Option 2": {"Suboption 2": {"Subsub 1":201, "Subsub 2":202},
             "Suboption 3": {"Subsub 3":203, "Subsub 4":204, "Subsub 5":205}
            }
    };

    $('input[name=demo1]').optionTree(option_tree);
```

Comment: Seems I up voted this a little too early - tried making a form and realized a few key features are missing: 1) I can't set different default select message per dropdown, for example "Please select country" and then "Please select state"; 2)Naming each sub-dropdown doesn't seem to be possible, it appends "_" to it, but then puts entire selection value into a field (works ok, but naming each sub drop-down would be nice).

Comment: @Sologoup 1)There is an empty_value param you can pass in to set the default message. Take a look at examples on the demo page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about blatant self promotion, but I had same problem earlier and wrote [Chained Selects](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) plugin to fit my needs. It is similar to what Glennular offered but with some differences. Instead of building the selects from JSON array it uses class attributes of HTML to figure out which options should be shown. For example:

```
<select id="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
</select>
```

You would then make them chained with following JavaScript:

```
$("#series").chained("#mark");
```

or if you prefer longer form:

```
$("#series").chainedTo("#mark");
```

You might also want to check the source of separate [demo page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html).

Comment: just a question about your chained selects. What if I want the option "3 Series" to belong to both BMW and Audi?

Comment: @xEnOn I looked into his stuff, apparantly you can add multiple classes. `value="series-3" class="bmw audi"`

Comment: @scragar I tried adding multiple classes earlier but it didn't seem to work.